# How to use boost stacktrace with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I was thinking to use the new `boost-stacktrace` library in my projects.

Therefore I tried the example in the documentation of `boost-stacktrace`, but seemingly the output wouldn't help me as it should?

This is my little test runner program:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

void my_signal_handler(int signum) {
    ::signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to("./backtrace.dump");
    ::raise(SIGABRT);
}

int fails() {
    abort();
    return 2;
}

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    ::signal(SIGSEGV, &my_signal_handler);
    ::signal(SIGABRT, &my_signal_handler);

    if (boost::filesystem::exists("./backtrace.dump")) {
        std::ifstream ifs("./backtrace.dump");
        boost::stacktrace::stacktrace st = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_dump(ifs);
        std::cout << "Previous run crashed:\n" << st << std::endl;
        ifs.close();
        boost::filesystem::remove("./backtrace.dump");
    }

    try {
        fails();
    }

    catch (...) {
    }
}
```

After starting it a second time it outputs:

```
Previous run crashed:
 0# 0x00AA3E0D
 1# 0x00AAFE53
 2# 0x00AA1346
 3# 0x579115DB
 4# 0x5790E170
 5# 0x5790EB92
 6# 0x579100EC
 7# 0x5790EAE4
 8# 0x578F84EC
 9# 0x578F86A1
10# 0x57912B8A
11# 0x00AA138C
12# 0x00AA1555
13# 0x00AC3C9E
14# 0x00AC3B80
15# 0x00AC3A2D
16# 0x00AC3CB8
17# BaseThreadInitThunk in kernel32
18# RtlInitializeExceptionChain in ntdll
19# RtlInitializeExceptionChain in ntdll
```

This is of no use for me. I expected something like `abort` is called in `fails` in line 15 of `main.cpp` for example.

Do I have to set some special compiler options in visual studio? Maybe it is also necessary to link some extra libraries or set some extra switches in `boost-stacktrace`?

I'm really clueless, how to get the behavior described in the docs.

Comment: Perhaps your build configuration is not setting the proper symbols. Check out the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I consulted the docs again and I found, that `#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_WINDBG` before including `#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>` would solve the issue.

Comment: @Aleph0: You should add your comment as an answer!